# Can I insert an External CSS File into a PDF generated by ITextScript

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Is it possible to add an external CSS file to a .pdf I am making with the library ITextSharp? To be clear I want to insert external CSS styling into a pdf I am MAKING not one that has already been made.

If not, is there a way I can apply CSS styling to my HTML I am inserting/converting to a .pdf? Maybe I can parse the external CSS file contents into a string then call a PDFDocument function that sets the body/global CSS, maybe something like document.setDocumentCSS(string);??

**I guess what I am asking is: what are the easiest/most efficient ways to insert losts of CSS into a ITextSharp generated pdf?**

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, you cannot use external CSS with itextSharp, instead you can use string builder and html to accomplish your results.

Check the following link :

[Dynamically creating .pdfs under the ITextSharp Free Licence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578801/dynamically-creating-pdfs-under-the-itextsharp-free-licence/9578935#9578935)